# How to prevent MS Office from adding shortcuts to Logitech's SetPoint?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, logitech-mouse

Everytime I start Word or Excel it re-adds Office shortcuts to Logitech's SetPoint software. Is there a way to prevent MS Office from doing this? I need to delete them everytime because they interfere with my own custom shortcuts.

[image: SetPoint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem and solved it the following way, I have Windows10 and mouse logitech M705.
Open the folder corresponding to your mouse (for M705 folder is 10000A2)
c:\ProgramData\Logishrd\SetPointP\Devices\PointingDevice\10000A2
Edit the only xml file in the folder: 10000A2.xml, removing the section:

```xml
        <Button Number="5" Name="4">
          <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
            <PARAM Button="5" />
            <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="BrowserForward" HandlerSetGroup="ForwardFloresGroup" >
              <AppOverride App="OUTLOOK.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_OutlookBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="MSIMN.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_OutlookExpressBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="WINWORD.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_WordBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="POWERPNT.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_PowerPointBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="MM.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_MindMapperBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="EXCEL.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_ExcelBack"/>
              <AppOverride App="NLNOTES.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_LotusNotesBack"/>
            </TriggerState>
          </Trigger>
        </Button>

        <Button Number="4" Name="5">
          <Trigger Class="ButtonPress">
            <PARAM Button="4" />
            <TriggerState Name="ButtonDownUp" HandlerSet="Back" HandlerSetGroup="BackFloresGroup" >
              <AppOverride App="OUTLOOK.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_OutlookForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="MSIMN.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_OutlookExpressForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="WINWORD.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_WordForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="POWERPNT.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_PowerPointForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="MM.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_MindMapperForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="EXCEL.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_ExcelForward"/>
              <AppOverride App="NLNOTES.exe" HandlerSet="AppOverride_LotusNotesForward"/>
            </TriggerState>
          </Trigger>
        </Button>
```

Save the file. In case saving is not possible, close the setpoint application and try again. If still not possible, save under other name and then try some tricks to replace the file.

Comment: It my message above some text did not paste. So you have to remove in mentioned file two sections with their contents:
<Button Number="5" Name="4"> and some lines below: <Button Number="4" Name="5">

Comment: Excellent! I have just edited the file for my mouse and this junk is finally gone! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the solution I proposed is not perfect. After removing the sections for button 4 and 5, those buttons does not have a specific function anymore.

Comment: Additionally the assignment for Office applications bounce back after PC restart.
The best solution I have now is not removing the Excel, Word etc. from the list but just removing buttons assignment in those applications.
If anyone edited XML file and does not have an original copy, will have to reinstall the Logitech software again.

Answer (score 1):

Lately, in WIN10 the Setpoint software does not show the mouse image with it's buttons.
It is possible to manually copy your own png files describing the mosue buttons which I did and it works, for 705 mouse:
c:\ProgramData\Logishrd\SetPointP\Devices\PointingDevice\10000A2\1.png and up to 9.png
Being able to see the pictures is very helpful for mouses with more than 4 buttons

Comment: Yeah, this really sucks. That's why I use an older version of the SetPoint software. For me the newest version that still has images is the 6.69.123. I tried newer ones and there was only the generic image. Logitech doesn't seem to care at all about it. This bug is like hundreds years old.